# NTP server script

Tags: windows, scripting, ntp

How can I synchronize a windows PC time to a NTP server using a batch script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Net Time command to do this:

```
Net Time /SETSNTP:time-a.nist.gov
```

This will set your machine to use the external server specified for its time server.

If you wish to set the machine to use an internal time server, you can use this command:

```
NET TIME \\TIMESRV /SET /YES
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use NTP you should really use it properly and install an NTP daemon. It will try keep your clock in sync using regular clock skew rather than jumping it at arbitrary times.

You can get a good Windows port of the standard NTPD from [here](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a batch script.

See my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/47578/windows-server-2008-sync-time-on-start-up/48495#48495) for some info on NTP in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have AD you don't need to do this, so long as the client is properly set up (i.e. no time server is set) it will automatically sync with the doamin hierarchy.

If you don't have AD you need to look at the NET TIME or W32TM commands.