# How to set common NTP server for all computers in AD

Tags: windows, active-directory, ntp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a frequent period for NTP client to sync with the NTP server.](https://serverfault.com/questions/111954/how-to-set-a-frequent-period-for-ntp-client-to-sync-with-the-ntp-server)

I want to set default NTP server to pool.ntp.org to all computers joining my domain.

How can I force this using AD MMC console?

Or I have to setup this using DHCP server?

Comment: Dupes galore for this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/111954/how-to-set-a-frequent-period-for-ntp-client-to-sync-with-the-ntp-server, http://serverfault.com/questions/50276/ntp-server-script, http://serverfault.com/questions/4298/best-way-to-synchronise-the-time-on-a-windows-2008-server, http://serverfault.com/questions/3403/how-do-i-configure-a-windows-domain-controller-to-use-an-external-time-server. All found just by searching for "windows ntp"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is really not a good idea.  By default, all Windows clients will obtain time from a domain controller and your domain controllers will obtain the time from your PDC emulator.  The only thing you want to do is set the server with the PDC emulator to sync from an external time source.

If you set individual time sources on each client, and they eventually become out of sync, then you will be unable to log in to your domain (Kerberos requires clocks to be in-sync by 5 minutes).